I'm trying to bulid a game tree with TikZ, but the bottom node will not work. Any suggestions?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, level distance=2.5cm, 
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=4.5cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}]
    \node {Up}
    child {
        node {Down}
        child {node {X, 1-X}}
        child {node {Up}
            child {node {I, 1-I}}
            child {node {Down}
                child {node {Y, 1-Y}}
                child {node {Up}
                    child {node {I, 1-I}}
                    child {node {W-C_u, W+C_d}}
                }
            }
        }
    }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



The issue I believe is just that you're using an underscore outside of math mode in the labels of the last node.
You can use one of the following
child {node {$W-C_u$, $W+C_d$}}
child {node {W-C\textsubscript{u}, W+C\textsubscript{d}}}
child {node {W-C\_u, W+C\_d}}

depending on what you're really looking for as output.

That worked! Such a simple fix haha. Thank you!
